# Distributing limited resources with choices

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm to figure out the maximum number of "products" that can be created given limited "resource choices".

For example, let's say I want to create an ABC and are given these resource choices:

- A or B: 3
- A or C: 1
- B: 1
- C: 1

In this case, I can create at most 2 ABC by selecting 2 A and 1 B from the first choice, and 1 C from the second choice. Then I have a total of 2 A, 2 B, and 2 C which can create 2 ABC.

**Is there an algorithm, other than brute forcing the permutations, which solves this problem?**

For completeness, here are the constraints in my actual problem:

- Max number of different resources in product: 10
- Max number of resource choices: 20
- Max quantity of a choice: 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved using [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) or using the [Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) to solve the so-called [Maximum Network Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) problem. It would take me quiet some time to try to explain any of the 2 mentioned algorithms, so I think you should take a look at some online resources. If you need to solve some real problem I suggest you to go through the algorithm(s) just to get idea how you can model this particular problem and then use some of the existing libraries. If you want to learn algorithms, feel free to write your implementation :)

Comment: I can see a straightforward LP formulation, but I can't see any (straightforward) guarantee that there will be an optimal integral solution.  (E.g. what stops the optimal solution to some problem from suggesting that 1.5 As and 1.5 Bs be produced from an "A or B: 3" resource?)

Comment: Awesome! Think I have something working using max flow: The 1st layer of vertices coming away from the source are the resource choices, with `capacity=quantity_of_resource_choice`. Then I have a second layer of vertices, one for each resource in the product and edges with infinite capacity going from layer 1 to layer 2 (based on whether the resource choice can fulfill the product resource). Then I have a 3rd layer of vertices, where `num_vertices=floor(size_of_product/total_input)`, and each vertex in layer 2 has a 1 capacity edge to each vertex in layer 3. Layer 3 to sink w/ infinite capacity